# Browser not waiting for specific image to load

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have some logic that takes longer in some browsers than others (*cough* IE *cough*).

So to improve UI feedback I'm trying to implement a loading spinner while the logic is being executed:

```
function generatePlaceholderbuttons() {
    var spinner = new Image();
    spinner.id = "spinner";
    spinner.addEventListener("load", function () {
        try {
            var emailForm = new EmailForm();
            emailForm.dynamicSQLToButtons();
        }
        finally {
            spinner.parentElement.removeChild(spinner);
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("dynamic-sql-textarea").parentElement.parentElement.appendChild(spinner);
    spinner.src = "../Content/spinner.gif";
}
```

Chrome kind of works, in that it seems to display the spinner *some times*, whereas in IE 11 the DOM just freezes while the long running logic is being executed, and then appears to display the spinner.

I haven't tried promises yet, because I'd ideally like to support older browsers.

**EDIT:**

So this does work, but this can't be the only way surely!

```
function generatePlaceholderbuttons(spinner) {
    spinner.style.visibility = "visible";
    setTimeout(function () {
        try {
            var emailForm = new EmailForm();
            emailForm.dynamicSQLToButtons();
        }
        finally {
            spinner.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You could try either tying the process to the next thread tick or animation frame; the re-render after a DOM modification isn't synchronous, or just hide the spinner until the process begins, rather than doing the image load dynamically.

Comment: I tried the easy suggestion first - show/hide - however it seems to suffer from the same delayed DOM render issue. I'll look into the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`dynamicSQLToButtons` appears to be synchronous, which is the reason of your slower browsers hanging for a long while. Convert this function so it will be asynchronous and use a callback, like

```
    try {
        var emailForm = new EmailForm();
        emailForm.dynamicSQLToButtons(function() {
            spinner.parentElement.removeChild(spinner);
        });
    }
    finally {
        //spinner.parentElement.removeChild(spinner);
    }
```

Comment: Good call but it behaves the same way. The problem is that DOM rendering isn't synchronous, so by the time I've told the DOM to append the new child, it's onto the long running code.

Comment: @Lee can you load this content inside an iframe as a separate page? That would keep the page around it functional.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but seems even more hacky than setting a timeout.

Comment: @Lee I strongly prefer the iframe approach if the alternative is a timeout, because in that case you can reliably handle this without freezing the browser, while in the case of a setTimeout you will always have to worry about the time provided being too small or too large. This approach separates concerns.

Comment: I just tried the iFrame method and unfortunately it seems to suffer from the same DOM render problem. From it's behaviour it would seem even showing/hiding of the iFrame is not synchronous. I can only conclude any native manipulation of the DOM is async.

Comment: @Lee maybe it's because they are on the same domain. I wonder whether the behavior would be the same if the page inside the iframe would be of a different domain (i.e. a subdomain).